# fwrite optimisation for video streaming

Tags: c++, rtsp, fwrite

I have created an FFMPEG pipeline to stream video frames to an RTSP server. I initiate my pipeline as follows:

```
FILE* openPipeLine =  _popen("ffmpeg -f rawvideo -r 10 -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format bgr24 -i pipe: -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rtsp rtsp://localHost:8554/mystream", "wb");
```

I then have a loop where I process the frames and end up with a Mat variable that contains the 720x1280 processed image. I then use the fwrite function to write the frame to the server as shown below.

```
 string filename = "file.mp4";
VideoCapture capture(filename);
Mat frame;
for( ; ; )
{
    capture >> frame;
    if(frame.empty())
        break;
    fwrite(frame.data, 1, 1280 * 720 * 3, openPipeLine);
}
```

Everything runs perfectly but the fwrite function takes approximately 0.1 seconds to run. I need it to be far more efficient. Is there a way to store the frames and batch write a group of frames instead of calling fwrite on each iteration? perhaps I can change the number 1 in the second input to fwrite?

Comment: Have you considered using two threads? One to capture the frames, one to write them to ffmpeg. A buffer between them (just a simple queue) can give ffmpeg time to ramp up its consumption rate and can absorb small perturbations in performance

Comment: Note that `fwrite` does its own buffering. You may want to follow up with `fflush` to ensure that ffmpeg sees the whole frame.